# Position a div element above another one

Tags: css, html

In the picture below, I am wanting to place the driftwood/bomb image over the image directly above it; hence, I want to remove/collapse the "space" between these two `div`s. The gap, however, is not caused by the markup itself, because as you can see the "bomb" is making the picture bigger on the height.

[image]

I would like to position the navigation bar on the "header" (so the brown top of the navigation is just below the header bottom), so the gap disappears. These images are meant to overlap.

I assume this can be done using CSS. But how? Whatever solution needs to work cross-browser.

HTML:

```
<header></header>
<nav></nav>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    width: 980px;
    height: 327px;
    background: url(../images/header.png);
}

nav {
    width: 980px;
    height: 180px;
    background: url(../images/menu.png);
}
```

Comment: can you post your html code.. or try to add float:left into both

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe a negative margin?

```
header {
    width: 980px;
    height: 327px;
    background: url(../images/header.png);
}

nav {
    width: 980px;
    height: 180px;
    background: url(../images/menu.png);
    margin: -90px auto 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NmUfT/

Answer (score 3):

Relative positioning could fix this for you:

```
nav {
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
}
```

Comment: I just realized, that's putting a space of equal size as the `top` underneath the `nav`: http://jsfiddle.net/NmUfT/2/ See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2280941/451969

Answer (score 1):

place the div inside the header div.

```
nav {
   position: relative;
   bottom: -30px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A top-margin with a negative value is indeed what you seek. If the nav would disappear beneath the header, you should change the nav's z-index. Try different numbers: 100, 1000, 10000 etc.