# CSS - Twitter's Bootstrap 2.x issues with Firefox and IE

Tags: css, firefox, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently developping a website using twitter Bootstrap as a base. I develop using Chrome and there is no problems on it but when viewing the same page with Firefox, the menu and the content position themselves weirdly, as if there is no space.

You can take a look there: 
http://www.penthousemontreal.com/
http://penthousemontreal.com/collections/moderne/

What could be causing the trouble?

Comment: Have you tried to investigate the problem?

Comment: I was wondering that it may be the sum of my span? the menu is span2 and the content span10, so it s a total of 12, as i saw in the documentation that bootstrap is a 12 columns.

Comment: Indeed. Are you using a grid layout or fluid layout? (Or you never touched it)

Comment: I never touched it but i guess it a grid: i have a <div  class="row"> and span like <div class="span4"> inside

Comment: maybe you checked while i was doing some modification, i changed the sum of the span to make them 10 and it looks ok, but when it s 12, it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update**

Your are using a `top: -100px;` (relative position) on the `.brand` class (the image in your nav bar). The image will still take space in FF / IE on it's original position. Cause the `float:left;` of this images your content floats on the right side of this 'empty space'. A solution can be found here: [CSS using negative relative positioning issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280625/css-using-negative-relative-positioning-issue). Replace top with margin-top:

```
.brand {
    margin-left: 20px !important;
    margin-top: -100px;
    position: relative;
  }
```

<strike>Maybe your bootstrap files are changed / corrupt. You import bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css (and bootstrap-responsive.css) from wp-content/themes/MMS/style.css which seems to be version Bootstrap v2.3.2.
When i load your site with `//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css` the problem is fixed. See: [image]</strike>

Comment: Just to make sure, when you loaded with my bootstrap files did you see the problem? I just downloaded a fresh bootstrap archive and changed it, but still the same issue http://i42.tinypic.com/2lxupfc.png

Comment: it is really strange, i did the same as you importing your link, but it doesn't fix it

Comment: The problem seems the image of your navbar. The .navbar .brand got a float left. The complete content got this float too. You don't see this cause .brand has  `top: -100px;`. Remove the `top: -100px;` to see the problem more clear. Also removing the image show it.

Comment: Indeed that was the problem! Thank you very much